# Entity Framework - Virtual Properties Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following class definitions

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{

    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IndependentClass IndependentClass { get; set; }

    public string IndependentClassName { get { return IndependentClass == null ? "<NULL>" : IndependentClass.Name; } }
}

public class Impl1 : AbstractClass
{
}

public class Impl2 : AbstractClass
{
}

public class IndependentClass
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Impl1 Impl1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Impl2> Impl2s { get; set; }
}
```

with these in my `Context.OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AbstractClass>().HasOptional(abs => abs.IndependentClass);
modelBuilder.Entity<IndependentClass>().HasRequired(ind => ind.Impl1);
modelBuilder.Entity<IndependentClass>().HasMany(ind => ind.Impl2s);
```

My initialization looks like this (with adding the arrays to the context and `context.SaveChanges()` trimmed)

```
var impl1s = new[]
{
    new Impl1() { Name = "a" },
    new Impl1() { Name = "b" },
    new Impl1() { Name = "c" }
}

var inds = new[]
{
    new IndependentClass() { Name = "A", Impl1 = impl1s[0] },
    new IndependentClass() { Name = "B", Impl1 = impl1s[1] }
}

var impl2s = new[]
{
    new Impl2() { Name = "a1", IndependentClass = inds[0] },
    new Impl2() { Name = "a2", IndependentClass = inds[0] },
    new Impl2() { Name = "b1", IndependentClass = inds[1] },
    new Impl2() { Name = "b2", IndependentClass = inds[1] },
    new Impl2() { Name = "c1", IndependentClass = null }
}
```

And finally I have a simple View that dumps each of the db collections. My problem is that the navigation properties aren't getting populated like I need them to. i.e., the output of my view is this:

```
Independent Classes:

    A: Impl1 = a, Impl2s = []
    B: Impl1 = b, Impl2s = []

Impl1s

    a: IndependentClass = <NULL>
    b: IndependentClass = <NULL>
    c: IndependentClass = <NULL>

Impl2s

    a1: IndependentClass = A
    a2: IndependentClass = A
    b1: IndependentClass = B
    b2: IndependentClass = B
    c1: IndependentClass = <NULL>
```

The IndepdendentClasses should have their Impl2s populated, and the first two Impl1s should have IndependentClasses populated.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model has three relationships with the following navigation properties:

- `AbstractClass.IndependentClass` <-> `IndependentClass.(NoNavigationProperty)`
- `IndependentClass.Impl1` <-> `Impl1.(NoNavigationProperty)`
- `IndependentClass.Impl2s` <-> `Impl2.(NoNavigationProperty)`

For each relationship one end of the association is not exposed as navigation property. It's not expected in this model that...

> The IndepdendentClasses should have their Impl2s populated, and the
>   first two Impl1s should have IndependentClasses populated

...because you don't populate `IndependentClass.Impl2s` in your initialization code nor do you fill `Impl1.IndependentClass`. You fill `Impl2.IndependentClass` but because this navigation property belongs to another relationship it doesn't affect `IndependentClass.Impl2s` at all.

If you want actually two relationships...

- `IndependentClass.Impl1` <-> `Impl1.IndependentClass`  (one-to-one)
- `IndependentClass.Impl2s` <-> `Impl2.IndependentClass` (one-to-many)

...you can't achieve that as long as your `AbstractClass` is an entity in your model with its own table because you must map between navigation properties of the types they are *declared* in, and `Impl1.IndependentClass` and `Impl2.IndependentClass` are inherited properties but they are not declared in `Impl1` and `Impl2`.

If you don't make `AbstractClass` an entity, i.e. don't use this abstract class in mapping code and don't have a `DbSet<AbstractClass>` in your context class, then the two relationships above are possible. For EF your model does not have any inheritance, instead it considers `Impl1` (and `Impl2`) as an entity that just contains its own properties plus the properties of the base class *as if* it were one class without base.

That's the reason why the mapping in your own answer works as you expect: You have defined the one-to-one relationship between `IndependentClass.Impl1` and `Impl1.IndependentClass` explicitly with Fluent API. The second relationship between `IndependentClass.Impl2s` and `Impl2.IndependentClass` is detected automatically by naming conventions as one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the solution is to replace

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AbstractClass>().HasOptional(abs => abs.IndependentClass);
modelBuilder.Entity<IndependentClass>().HasRequired(ind => ind.Impl1);
modelBuilder.Entity<IndependentClass>().HasMany(ind => ind.Impl2s);
```

with

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Impl1>()
    .HasOptional(abs => abs.IndependentClass)
    .WithRequired(ind => ind.Impl1);
```

but I'm not sure why I don't have to change anything for the Impl2's.

Comment: Because with this mapping `AbstractClass` isn't an entity anymore (and doesn't have its own table) in contrast to the mapping in your question. `Impl1.IndependentClass` and `Impl2.IndependentClass` are now two separate navigation properties (your `abs` above is an `Impl1`, not an `AbstractClass`), one refering to `IndependentClass.Impl1` defined by your mapping code above, the other refering to `IndependentClass.Impl2s` that is mapped automatically as one-to-many by convention. Your new model has two relationships, the old one had three.

Comment: ohhhhh, that makes a lot of sense. If you answer the question with that, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I had actually started to write an answer but stopped when your own answer appeared. Fortunely SO saves a draft, so I could restore this now and expand a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the properties in your constructor.

EF will only do that for you if the instances come from an EF DataContext.

When you write `new Impl2()`, EF is not involved at all.

Comment: My View gets the objects from a data context, so that isn't the issue